# Sending e-mail with attachment from Image View

Tags: ios, swift, email, attachment

Ok, im a bit further now. I got the email button working within the app, but it doesnt add the picture that i have selected in UIImageview in the e-mail. Can someone tell me how to add the picture selected to the email body?

```
@IBAction func FotoKnop(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func chooseImageFromPhotoLibrary() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func chooseFromCamera() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    imageView.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
    // start e-mail

    @IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
        }
    }

    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property
        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["jvanhattem@it-serve.nl"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("Mail vanuit PicMail")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Onderstaand de doorgestuurde informatie", isHTML:
            false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }

    // MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Method
    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Give me feedback if it worked..

Comment: Anokrize, thanks for the feedback. When i implement your code i get errors in 2 lines: func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController { and     if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {. It says use of undeclared type MFmailComposeViewController.

Comment: Look at the imports above did you implement them?

Comment: What imports should i use?

Comment: You need to use MessegeUI.framework

Comment: What do you mean? Where to implement and what code?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at documentation for [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/index.html)
You can set the recepients and attachment using `setToRecipients:` and `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code fur your email function:

```
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["nurdin@gmail.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}
```

And this code in your function for the action or where you want to add...

```
let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        // On Success
    } else {
        // Error handling here
    }
```